# Why isn't "1010 0000" a valid BCD representation?

Tags: bcd

I came across this in the book "Programming the Z80", it was an exercise question that wasn't answered.

Comment: `1010 0000` would be `A0` hexadecimal. Any more questions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're trying to represent decimal values with binary numbers. You can only use representations of numbers between 0 and 9.

Valid BCD 4-bit chunks:

```
0000 - 0
0001 - 1
0010 - 2
0011 - 3
0100 - 4
0101 - 5
0110 - 6
0111 - 7
1000 - 8
1001 - 9
```

Invalid BCD 4-bit chunks:

```
1010 - 10
1011 - 11
1100 - 12
1101 - 13
1110 - 14
1111 - 15
```

Examples:

```
0101 0011 - 53
1001 0111 - 97
1000 1001 0100 - 894
1010 0000 - (10)0 // We can't represent 10 in a single decimal digit
```

The values 10 to 15 would be valid in a BCH ([binary coded hexadecimal](https://www.ia.omron.com/support/faq/answer/15/faq02201/)) context. The previous invalid example would result in something like this:

```
1010 0000 - A0
```